# DTD error not reported when wrong tag is read with Xerces SAX parser

Tags: java, xml, dtd, saxparser, xerces

I'm trying to parse and validate a quite simple XML file with the Apache Xerces SAX2 validating parser.
The DTD is referenced from the XML file and my simple entity resolver can successfully return with a proper InputStream for the DTD file.
I have a very basic tag structure, it does not relevant to name them so I simply give a letter to the XML tags.
The main tag is A, there could be zero or more B's inside the A tag, but only B's. And there is zero or more C's inside the B's.
So a proper XML would be:

```
<A>
<B><C>somecharacters</C></B>
</A>
```

I created some unit test and experienced a strange behaviour. I thought if I give a similar XML to the parser as above, but with only closing tag for the C without a matching opening tag and without the parent element B, the parser will report a DTD validation error. 
Here's the intentionally non-valid XML example according to the DTD:

```
<A>
<C>somecharacters</C></B>
</A>
```

It's quite obvious that this XML fragment is not well-formed.
Unfortunately (or I don't understand something with the SAX parser) the parser calls the ContentHandler's startElement method for the C tag, and after that, calls the characters method for the characters inside the C tag.
The DTD clearly states that the A tag could only have B tags as children, and NOT C's because C's firstly needs to be nested inside the B's.
What I don't understand is why the parser calls the characters method after realizing that the nested C is not in a good place

My application logic in the ContentHandler methods rely on the assumption about the tags are nested according to the DTD and I don't want to fill these 3 methods with null-checker and error handling code because I assume this is the DTD validator's job.

My code to setup the parser is (the exception handling part is not relevant) :

```
    private static final String VALIDATION_FEATURE = "http://xml.org/sax/features/validation";
    private static final String SAX_PARSER_IMPLEMENTATION = "org.apache.xerces.parsers.SAXParser";
    ......
    XMLReader parser = XMLReaderFactory.createXMLReader(SAX_PARSER_IMPLEMENTATION);
    parser.setFeature(VALIDATION_FEATURE, true);
    parser.setErrorHandler(new CustomErrorHandler());
    parser.setEntityResolver(entityResolver);
    parser.setContentHandler(handler);

    InputSource inputSource = new InputSource(stream);
    try {
        parser.parse(inputSource);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new ControlFileReadException("Error while parsing the control file.", e);
    } catch (SAXException e) {
        if (e.getCause() instanceof IncorrectCounterNameException) {
            throw new IncorrectCounterNameException(e.getCause());
        } else {
            throw e;
        }
    }

    private final class CustomErrorHandler implements ErrorHandler {
    public void warning(SAXParseException spe) throws SAXException {
        throw spe;
    }

    public void fatalError(SAXParseException spe) throws SAXException {
        throw spe;
    }

    public void error(SAXParseException spe) throws SAXException {
        throw spe;
    }
}
```

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Can you please provide the relevant parts from your code. Especially the parser setup.

Comment: thanks for the advice, the question was modified.

Comment: What does your `CustomErrorHandler` look like? From the [javadocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/org/xml/sax/ErrorHandler.html):  _In order to detect validity errors, an ErrorHandler that does something with error() calls must be registered._

Comment: It simply throw all the possible exceptions, I think it's enough to handle errors.

Comment: One more thing to remark:
If I parse with a DefaultHandler in the first run and then parse with my custom content handler then the parser can handle DTD errors/warnings correctly. But it smells very workaroundy.